# Is it possible to remove an attribute (variable) from object in java?

Tags: java, object, reflection, attributes

I have a lots of classes that extends from one class

Also I have one method that its argument is that parent class and create query base on attribute of those classes.

sometimes I need to ignore some attribute from result query.

so is it possible to remove some attribute of object?

```
class A1 extends Model {
    public String field1 = "";
    public String field2 = "";

    public String table = "A1";

    @Override
    public String getTable() {
        return this.table;
    }
}

class A2 extends Model {
    public String field1 = "";
    public String field2 = "";
    public String field3 = "";

    public String table = "A2";

    @Override
    public String getTable() {
        return this.table;
    }
}

class Utility {
    public static String query(Model params) {
        Field[] fields = params.getClass().getFields();
        String head = "INSERT INTO " + params.getTable() + "(";
        String tail = "VALUES (";
        for(Field field : fields) {
            String key = field.getName();
            String val;
            try {
                val = field.get(params);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                val = null;
            }
            head += key + ",";
            tail += "'" + val + "',";
        }
        head = head.substring(head,0,head.length() -1) + ")";
        tail = tail.substring(tail,0,tail.length() -1) + ")";
        return head + tail;
    }
}
```

I call query method by sending one model

```
A1 data = new A1();
data.field1 = "Name";
data.field2 = "Family";
String query = Utility.query(data);
```

I just want to remove field2 from query how can I do that?

thanks for any help

Comment: What does your ```Model``` class look like?

Comment: public abstract class Model { public abstract String getTable(); }

Comment: what do you mean by remove from query? could you give expected output for query?

Comment: i want to output be like this: INSERT INTO A1(field1) VALUES ('Name')

Comment: i dont think you can remove something by reflection but you may use the api to alter certain class structure.

Comment: I want object of A1 has not any field2, is it possible? I don't want to null it and then check the null value because null has meaning to database

Comment: @vikeng21 do you know any API that could alter class structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement an annotiation. Let's call it `@DontPersist`. Use it to mark fields which should not get persisted. In `Utility.query()` you can check for the annotation with reflection.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you mean use @DontPersist in class definition? sometimes I need to use the mention field and sometimes I don't want to use it. If I use it in class declaration it will be ignored forever.

Comment: If you need dynamic behaviour you must somehow specify which fields must (not) be used. Since Java doesn't allow you to add/remove fields on runtime, you must provide a list of field names to exclude/include either to the model class or to `Utility.query()`.

Comment: you mean i create method in model class that set exclude fields and then check it in Utility.query? it could be an answer. can I do it via setAccessible and check it with isAccessible in Utility.query?

Comment: Yes. If you need a dynamic solution, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As your Model class does not implement anything (it could be an interface, but that's another topic), you can extend it creating a class with less attributes when necessary (an anonymous class will do the job).

Anyway, I think you should refactor your code: why not using a List to store fields? It's easier and it does not need reflection.

I'll use something like:

```
public class Model extends ArrayList{

    public Model(String name) { tableName=name;}

    private String tableName;

    public String getTable() {return tableName}


}
```

And then you can iterate over the Array to obtain the field names.

Comment: thanks for your answer, another usage of those classes is using by tomee webservice they are parameters in SOAP wsdl

Comment: can we create anonymous class on runtime?